# React App, Containerized with Docker, Dispatching Incorrect Action?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, docker, express

**EDIT:** Solved - I had to re-run npm run build, as I was not using the latest version of my app to build the container. (If someone is able to help point me in the direction of a resource that explains why this is, that would be helpful - thank you!)

First question, so please feel free to roast me. I have a simple CRUD React app I'm developing and looking to containerize it as practice. The routes/sagas work locally; however, when I bring the containers up, it seems like my dispatch is being handled by the wrong generator function in the correct saga. I receive a 500 error from the server, which directs me to the `"UPDATE_EXPERIENCE"` generator function (below). I'll drop some code blocks below to hopefully illustrate, but please let me know if there's anything else that can help here. Thank you in advance!

**Toggle Functionality Handler**

```
  // toggle functionality for external toggle
  const handleChange = (event) => {
    const updatedToggle = !checked;
    setChecked(updatedToggle);
    dispatch({
      type: "SHOW_EXTERNAL_UPDATE", // WHY IS THIS NOT WORKING
      payload: {
        expId: experience.this_id,
        toggle_ext: updatedToggle,
      },
    });
  };
```

**Saga**

```
function* experienceSaga() {
  yield takeEvery("FETCH_USER_EXPERIENCE", fetchExperiences);
  yield takeEvery("ADD_USER_EXPERIENCE", addExperience);
  yield takeEvery("UPDATE_EXPERIENCE", updateExperience);
  yield takeEvery("DELETE_EXPERIENCE", deleteExperience);
  yield takeEvery("SHOW_EXTERNAL_UPDATE", toggleExternal);
}
```

**Generator function for separate put requests**

```
// more general put route to handle updates
function* updateExperience(action) {
  try {
    const response = yield fetch("/api/experience", {
      method: "PUT",
      body: JSON.stringify(action.payload),
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
    });
    if (!response.ok) {
      throw new Error("Network response for PUT was not OK");
    }
    yield put({ type: "FETCH_USER_EXPERIENCE" });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("Experience update failed: ", error);
  }
}

**Generator function to handle the toggle**
// function to handle toggling the external data display switch
function* toggleExternal(action) {
  console.log("IN TOGGLING");
  try {
    const response = yield fetch(`/api/experience/toggleExternal`, {
      method: "PUT",
      body: JSON.stringify(action.payload),
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
    });
    if (!response.ok) {
      throw new Error("Network response for PUT was not OK");
    }
    yield put({ type: "FETCH_USER_EXPERIENCE" });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("Experience update failed: ", error);
  }
}
```

**Server route for the toggle**

```
// PUT route to handle the external data toggle so that
// it persists
router.put("/toggleExternal", rejectUnauthenticated, (req, res) => {
  QUERY = `UPDATE experiences SET toggle_external=$1 WHERE id=$2;`;
  pool
    .query(QUERY, [req.body.toggle_ext, req.body.expId])
    .then((result) => res.sendStatus(200))
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error(error);
      res.sendStatus(500);
    });
});
```

**Server route for all other put requests**
`router.put("/", rejectUnauthenticated, (req, res) => {`

I've been doing a ton of googling/making small changes to the URLs, the generator function names, and the dispatch types. I would expect the client to successfully send the server the toggle request, updating the database with the toggle state then reflecting that in the front end.